# Ubuntu running `pip install` gives error 'The following required packages can not be built: * freetype'

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, matplotlib, pip

When performing `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I get the following error during the stage where it is installing `matplotlib`:

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [pkg-config information for 'freetype2' could
                        not be found.]
```

...

```
The following required packages can not be built:

                    * freetype
```

Shouldn't `pip install -r requirements.txt` also install freetype? How should freetype be installed in Ubuntu 12.04 so it works with `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

No. `pip` will not install system-level dependencies. This means `pip` will not install RPM(s) (*Redhat based systems*) or DEB(s) (*Debian based systems*).

To install system dependencies you will need to use one of the following methods depending on your system.

**Ubuntu/Debian:**

```
apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

To search for packages on Ubuntu/Debian based systems:

```
apt-cache search <string>
```

e.g:

```
apt-cache search freetype | grep dev
```

---

**Redhat/CentOS/Fedora:**

```
yum -y install freetype-devel
```

To search for packages on Redhat/CentOS/Fedora based systems:

```
yum search <string>
```

e.g:

```
yum search freetype | grep devel
```

---

**Mac OS X:** (*via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)*)

```
brew install freetype
```

To search for packages on Mac OS X based systems:

```
brew search <string>
```

e.g:

```
brew search freetype
```

Comment: Sorry it's called ``freetype2`` these days. Updated.

Comment: `apt-get install freetype2-devel` gives the same error too... Could it be `apt-get install freetype*`? That seems to want to install many other packages

Comment: That will probably work too :) Sorry I believe it's called ``libfreetype2-devel``. I'll updates my answer again :/

Comment: I think the `-devel` convention is for RPM and the `-dev` convention is for DEB.  Try `apt-cache search '^libfreetype.*-dev$'` which gives `libfreetype6-dev`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks :) Bit hard to test without access to Debian/Ubuntu machines :/ Our work only uses RHEL/CentOS :)

Comment: You can always use http://packages.ubuntu.com if you don't have access to a computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yeah I did but had trouble finding the right package because of the **dev** vs. **devel** convention -- Got myself confused :)

Comment: fwiw, `brew install freetype` helped me on OSX

Comment: Mac OS X Users: `brew install pkg-config` will help `pip` find `freetype`

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian users also need the package in @Sudipta Basak's answer

Answer (score 148):

I had to install libxft-dev in order to enable matplotlib on ubuntu server 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev
```

And then I could use

```
sudo easy_install matplotlib
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I also needed to install libxft-dev. Thanks for this extra info

Comment: Why not directly use sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib as recommended here: http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html

Comment: I already had libfreetype6-dev installed.  This helped for me on ubuntu 14.10, thanks!

Comment: the libxft-dev thing is what did it for me!  thanks!

Comment: Apparently, the real dependency here is `pkg-config`, which `libxft-dev` also installs as a dependency. So, the right answer would be to run `apt-get install libfreetype6-dev pkg-config`

Comment: on WSL2 I also had to install `libxft-dev`

Answer (score 30):

A workaround is to do `sudo apt-get install pkg-config` which I found [in this github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/).

Comment: installing ``pkg-config`` was the missing unintuitive step for me as well, this when installing ``matplotlib`` in a docker container with ``ubuntu:14.04`` as base-image.

Comment: This also fixed it for me as well on a virtualbox VM. Looks like `pkg-config` is what is needed for virtual machine installations.

Answer (score 7):

None of the existing answers worked for me to upgrade matplotlib on Ubuntu. This is what ultimately work for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-dep python-matplotlib
$ pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

Answer (score 7):

This command will download all dependencies.

For python 2.x

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

For python 3.x

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

After installing, you can try

```
(sudo) pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, it worked after I installed `blt-dev` package.

```
$sudo apt-get install blt-dev
$pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: blt-dev needs `apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` to run so it is automaticly installed with blt-dev.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Mint an none of this answers worked for me, I needed to:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Python 3.6 on Windows, but then I switched to Python 3.5.2 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This command `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` failed for me on ubuntu 16.04,
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2) but 
     2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed`

So I downloaded installed freetype from the [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/latest/download?source=files), credit to this [guide](http://newcoder.io/dataviz/part-0/)

```
$ tar -xvjf freetype-x.y.tar.bz2  # extract the downloaded version file
$ cd freetype-x.y/ 
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

switched to virtualenv and `pip install matplotlib` and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I followed James Mills' answer to install freetype. But still, although freetype was installed, the program was still failing. I believe this was because the program was not able to find the path of freetype. The following command solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

I found this solution on https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/