# Installing matplotlib on Codenvy

Tags: python, matplotlib, codenvy

Anyone have experience installing matplotlib on Codenvy(https://codenvy.com)?

I keep getting following errors trying to run my application:

```
[DOCKER]le "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/version.py", line 343, in _cmp

[DOCKER]

[DOCKER]if self.version < other.version:

[DOCKER]

[DOCKER]Error: unorderable types: str() < int()

[DOCKER]

[DOCKER]------------------------------------

[DOCKER]     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tcimm8pc/matplotlib

[DOCKER][ERROR] The command [/bin/sh -c cd /tmp/application && sudo virtualenv /env && sudo /env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt] returned a non-zero code: 1

[ERROR] We are having trouble starting the runner and deploying application Python. Either necessary files are missing or a fundamental configuration has changed.

[ERROR] Unable to retrieve the application logs from the runner.: You tried to detect unknown message. Please, check your message. Your message: The command [/bin/sh -c cd /tmp/application && sudo virtualenv /env && sudo /env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My requirements.txt contains:

```
numpy
matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is the following:

matplotlib: yes [1.4.3]
python: yes [2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24)  [GCC 4.9.2]] platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS

numpy: yes not found. pip may install it below.

six: yes six was not found.pip will attempt to install it after matplotlib.

dateutil: yes dateutil was not found. It is required for date axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
pytz: yes pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install it after matplotlib.

tornado: yes tornado was not found. It is required for the WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to install it after matplotlib.

pyparsing: yes pyparsing was not found. It is required for mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to install it after matplotlib.
pycxx: yes Couldn't import.  Using local copy.

libagg: yes pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not be found. Using local copy.

freetype: no  The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may need to install the development package.

png: no  pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not be found.

qhull: yes pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be found. Using local copy.

Some dependencies are missing.

Take a look at similar threads:

[Matplotlib compilation error: TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024731/matplotlib-compilation-error-typeerror-unorderable-types-str-int)

[Installing matplotlib and its dependencies without root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904841/installing-matplotlib-and-its-dependencies-without-root-privileges)

Comment: Thanks for the answer  -  yes I do realize I have missing dependencies.  What I am looking for is how to solve this issue in Codenvy Python environment.

Comment: Codenvy Python environment does not differ from a local linux machine in terms of configuration. You'll need to create your custom environment there, rather than use the default one. Here are some docs http://docs.codenvy.com/user/builders-and-runners/#custom-machines http://docs.codenvy.com/user/tutorials/building-custom-runtime/