# Elastic Beanstalk Matplotlib cannot build freetype

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a flask application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I am having a very head time getting it to install matplotlib. Suggestions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533455/2327821) for how to solve the problem involve installing packages from ubuntu, which I cannot do for Elastic Beanstalk. I am trying to install matplotlib 2.0.0 and I get the following error:

```
* The following required packages can not be built:
* freetype, png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `packages` key as described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages to install packages during your EB deploy.

Something like the following might work:

**.ebextensions/01-install-freetype.config**

```
packages: 
  yum:
    freetype: []
    png: []
```

Although on my system, freetype is already installed...